# ViewPager not responding to horizontal swipe for a couple of seconds after pulling up or pulling down the collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an activity with a `CoordinatorLayout` as root layout. The *root layout contains*
1) `AppBarLayout`(containing the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`) and
2) `ViewPager` (`app:layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`).

When I pull the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` **completely up(hidden) or completely down(fully shown)**, the `ViewPager` **does not respond to horizontal swipes for a couple of seconds, especially fast swipes**. The `ViewPager` somehow starts responding after that. How to solve this problem?